# Grub problem on ubuntu

Tags: grub2

It's my first launch of Ubuntu.  I wanted to install it with my windows 8 . I downloaded 16 lts version iso.  Made flash drive with Ubuntu.  And set  uefi flash drive for first boot option . Then when it launch  it showed me something called grub . 2nd version .  Black display  with grub> . Can someone explain what is it ? what to do next ? I thought that it continue to install like windows .I'm really noob .

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card chip? Which software did you use to create USB flash drive live installer? Also link on how to create a  bootable DVD or USB flash drive, Windows or Ubuntu, Min hardware requirements
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

That black display of grub indicates that the system is not able to find the boot option in your flash drive .

May be your flash disk is not successfully created ..or you have chosen wrong option for launching.

Just change the boot order and see if your previous windows is opening or not.

Then check options for your flash disk those are usb disk(uefi)
And           usb disk ..
If your windows is of gpt partition scheme just select first uefi option in bios.
If not then select another.

If you want to check your partition scheme then 
Open command prompt in windows as win+R .
Then type cmd

Type diskpart..
Type list disk
In that under gpt column if it shows * 
Then your system is in uefi. Else msdos.

So select according to this .
Definitely this will work if i got the correct problem of yours..

Hope it could help you..